# Django - template context processors - breaking my app

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I was trying to set up a template context processor like [this article mentions](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) so that I could provide information to every template.

I wrote this function in views.py:

```
def items_in_cart(request):
    """Used by settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS to provide an item count
    to every template"""
    cart, lines = get_users_cart_and_lines(request)
    return {'items_in_cart': lines.count()}
```

And then I added this line to settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('Store.views.items_in_cart',)
```

But now whenever I go to any page I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /

Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.
```

Did I do something wrong?  What's going on here?  I tried doing what the error said, and then it will render a page with all of my style sheets and images missing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django has a default set of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, which you need to manually add when adding your own. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

Depending on your Django version these are different, however if using Django 1.3 you might have something as follows

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "Store.views.items_in_cart",
)
```

Comment: hmm, can I just add mine to the existing default list?  E.g., TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = secret_default_location.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + ('Store.views.items_in_cart',)

Comment: You should be able to use TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('Store.views.items_in_cart',) to append to the defaults

Comment: The default django settings can be imported using `from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` above your line to append. You can then append to this using `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('Store.views.items_in_cart',)`

Comment: In Django 1.10 the value is removed from `global_settings` and the new `TEMPLATES` setting should be used. How should code like the above which adds to the default setting be migrated? Should they just be included manually? Is there even a default any more?