# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Enable 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-1.9

I started a new project and am getting:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Enable 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATES setting in order to use the admin application.
```

I followed the django docs for 1.9:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    }
]
```

What could be the issue (how does it want me configure)? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099330/django-template-context-processors-breaking-my-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005127/django-admin-breaks-after-upgrading-to-1-8-1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add it into [`context_processors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) list in the [`OPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Actually, it does. Here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) to the section explaining that.