# Where is django TEMPLATES

Tags: python, django, linux, cuckoo

I need to find Django TEMPLATES location to add in a line under 'context_processors' om 'OPTIONS'

I researched and found this which looks to be my problem solver, however I am unable to find the location of the document where I am supposed to input the details specified: [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Enable 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005647/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-enable-django-contrib-auth-context)

The project only relies on Django as a plugin so I am in no means experienced with setting up Django.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            ]
        }
    }
]

I can
```

not find the 'TEMPLATES' document.

Comment: The `settings.py`

Answer (score 2):

You put all project configurations in settings.py right at the top of the project

Comment: Thank you, but I can only seem to find the template for the settings: settings.py.tpl - and to my surprise, even in this file the necessary line already is present.
I get the error when running cuckoo webserver (using mongodb) in the very beginning when it is performing system checks, if thats to any help. I imagine the django settings.py is to find in my 'project' somewhere, would that be in the mongodb data somewhere?